# Why would a JSon string be evaluated to a different value?

Tags: c#, json.net

This is my first post here, so if I'm not detailed enough - please let me know.

I'm using Newtonsoft.JSON to process a JSON string. I've not had a problem with JSON and/or Newtonsoft.JSON before, and in my current project it mostly just works as expected. But sometimes it produces an unexpected error.

I've been tearing my hair out trying to find a solution, but it seems quite obscure - I've not been able to find a problem/solution that seems even vaguely related.

Here is a simplified version...
The JSON string I'm using is this (jsonResponse in the example below):
d={"count":1,"result":[{"CarID":31888,"CarName":"My Awesome Car","Year":"1923","Colour":"lime green","SomethingInteresting":"m","OtherStuff":"more detail","Status":"Buggered"}]}

Here's the code I'm using:

```
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResponse);

//get rid of annoying root element d
string d = dynObj.d;
dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(d);

foreach(var car in dynObj.result)
{
    Car c = new Car();
    c.CarID = car.CarID;
    //other stuff 
    c.SomethingInteresting = car.SomethingInteresting;  //this is where it fails (sometimes)
    //other stuff

    cars.Add(c);

    Console.WriteLine(c.ToString());

}
```

Most of the time it works just fine. But occasionally it fails, and I can't work out why.

It's the 'SomethingInteresting' value.
In this example, the value is "m". 
When this issue occurs, if I "watch" the variables in visual studio, car.SomethingInteresting = "m", but the assignment to c.SomethingInteresting is "109 'm'"

So, evaluated, my
    c.SomethingInteresting = car.SomethingInteresting;
becomes
    "109 'm'" = "m"

It consistently fails on the same row (string), but the same value for 'SomethingInteresting' might be the same for previous rows that have no problem.

How/why might this be?
It's just a plain text JSON string. Why would this only be a problem sometimes? And where's the "109" coming from?

I can't work it out. Hoping somebody might be able to provide some insight.
Thanks

Comment: @Nkosi They do since they have JSON embedded in JSON as a string. But they should put the actual JSON there and not a version with escapes where they don't belong.

Comment: Please put the exact string into the question, not a version of it that has escapes inserted where they most likely don't exist. Don't copy it from the debugger.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen yeah you are right. I missed that looking at the way it was formatted.

Comment: updated to exclude escapes, as suggested.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] for your problem?  I have tried variously escaped versions of your `jsonResponse` string taken from both versions of your question, and either the first call to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` fails with a parse error, or the line `string d = dynObj.d;` fails with a `RuntimeBinderException`.  Nothing I have done gets as far as the `c.SomethingInteresting = car.SomethingInteresting;` statement.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/6AKd97 for one attempt.  Without some way to reproduce the problem we can't help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks people for your help. Turns out it was a red-herring all along. My c.SomethingInteresting was declared a char, so the 109 is the ascii value for 'm', which was showing in the "watch". My actual issue was entirely unrelated, but I honed in on this because 'it looked odd' and I thought it was my issue. The pitfalls of late-night coding I guess.